# How to call a function when video is ended

Tags: angular7

Im working on Anguar7 Project and i have the following difficulty.

I'm loading video player in a html file and this html file is located inside my asset folder.
Now i'm loading a component with iframe tag. inside to iframe tage i'm loading the above html.
Now i want to call a function from my component once that video is ended.